# Export assets - Large extra space

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export

Export Assets giving large extra white space, inconsistently: top bottom left right. Never had this problem before. Happens no matter what format is chosen.

In Illustrator:
[image: In Illustrator]

When exported:
[image: When exported]

Comment: Yes well, the artboard isn’t the edge for when only a few items are bring exported. This is so ridiculous. A google search now has seen this problem reported for years. Something that Freehand, 10 years ago, didn’t have an issue with. I’d expect in 2018 it would have become smart enough! So guess I’ll have to export the items, then trim in Photoshop.

Comment: Did my answer not help? You're still having issues after trying those 3 options?

Comment: Did you read my reply? Exporting with the artboard only works for the ENTIRE image, and I have to be sure to size with precision. If I want to export only some of the items, such as the "icon", trimming to the artboard doesn't work. So, as stated above, I will have to export, then trim in Photoshop, which seems unnecessary and counterintuitive.

Comment: I am not understanding. I am explaining how to save only what is seen/on the artboard. Which you would make a specific size. So you wouldn't have the extra white space. Isn't that your problem?

Comment: Do you know how to use the Asset Export panel? That allows you to export some or all of what is in the file.

If I want to export the entire image, as you explained, I have to size the artboard EXACTLY to the size of the image. If it is any larger, there will be white space.

If I want to export only some items, selecting or not selecting "Use Artboards" will make no difference.

Yes, that is correct; yes, I've tried it.

I appreciate your time and effort, but if you don't understand it any better at this point, please just let it go, or let someone else answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The extra space is there because of the clipping mask used for the wood texture. **Adobe Illustrator does not trim to the clipping mask when using the Export Assets panel**. [This is a bug in Illustrator and has been reported](https://illustrator.uservoice.com/forums/333657-illustrator-feature-requests/suggestions/20359933-option-to-export-to-clipping-mask-boundaries).

You have a couple of work arounds:

**1)** Move the graphic with a clipping mask to the Libraries CC panel. Then move the artwork from the libraries panel back to the artboard. Delete the original graphic with the clipping mask or hide that object. Move the artwork from the artboard to the export asset panel.

**I do not recommend using the following but they still work.**

**2)** Use multiple artboards for each individual asset you want to export. You would then have to export multiple times for the various sizes you want for your assets.

**3)** Create a new Illustrator file for only the graphics that use a clipping mask. Then place that Illustrator file in your other Illustrator file that you will be exporting the assets from.

Comment: 1) didn't work properly, as the drop shadow was clipped off on the right and bottom to the size of the octagon is was created from.  
  
3) That illustrator file must be the exact dimensions, but not undoable.  
  
2) Might be the most effective.